# Tkinter: pass arguments when threading a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to pass some arguments while threading a function, this is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageGrab
import time

import threading


class Flashing(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

       self.first_label = tk.Label(self, image="", foreground="black")
       self.first_label.pack(padx=50, side="left", anchor="w")

       self.button = tk.Button(
           self,
           text="start",
           command=threading.Thread(target=self.flash_all, args=[label, img]).start(),
       )

       self.button.pack()

   def flash_all(self, label, img):
       for num in range(6):
           num += 1
           if (num % 2) == 0:
               print("{0} is Even".format(num))
               time.sleep(1)
               label.config(text="one)
           if (num % 2) == 1:
               print("{0} is Odd".format(num))
               time.sleep(1)
               self.bip1.play(loops=0)
               label.config(text='two')
           if num == 6:
               time.sleep(1)
               self.bip2.play(loops=0)
               label.config(text='three')
               time.sleep(5)
               label.config(image="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = tk.Tk()
   Flashing(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
   root.mainloop()
```

But I'm getting this error

```
(virt)
```

What shoudl I change to fix it?

Important: I've trimmed and change some label in my code to make it more easy to read. The original work fine except for the error I've mention.
Thanks you all

Comment: Not sure if it's the entire problem, but you're missing a quote here: `label.config(text="one)`.

Comment: When you "trim and change.. easy to read", make sure the "easy to read" version of code still executes and generates the same error.  Other folks have posted code they have never run which is no help for those of us who try to generate the same error with the same code on their own systems.

Comment: `args=[label, img]` - `label` and `img` are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Without using threads:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Flashing(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.num = -1
        self.timer_numer = None

        self.first_label = tk.Label(self, image="", foreground="black")
        self.first_label.pack(padx=50, side="left", anchor="w")

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="start", command=self.flash_all)
        self.button.pack()
        # We make a list over which we will iterate.
        self.list_text = ["one", "two","one", "two","one", "two",
                          "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three"]

    def flash_all(self):
        # Create a timer - run the function once a second.
        self.timer_numer = self.after(1000, self.flash_all)
        self.num += 1
        print(f"{self.num} is {self.list_text[self.num]}")
        self.first_label.config(text=self.list_text[self.num])
        if self.num >= 11:
            self.first_label.config(text="")
            # We stop the timer.
            self.after_cancel(self.timer_numer)
            self.num = -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    flash = Flashing(root)
    flash.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```